# Application throw cant find module babel-preset-es2015

Tags: mysql, angular, reactjs, mongodb

I have this error in my application

[image]

What can i do to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You should install babel-preset-es2015

Run

```
npm i babel-preset-es2015
```